# error C3699: '^' : cannot use this indirection on type 'std::string'

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I am trying to access lync from my application in this code I am getting errors.

```
error C3699: '^' : cannot use this indirection on type 'std::string'
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::String ^' to 'std::string *'
    1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
    1>        Cannot convert a managed type to an unmanaged type
```

My code is as follows:

```
 #using <Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll>
 #using <Microsoft.Lync.Utilities.dll>

 //namespace provided that DLL
 using namespace Microsoft::Lync::Model;

  //Function which is using that DLL
   void getusername()
  {
   LyncClient ^lyncClient;
   string     ^text=lyncClient->Self->Contact->GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType::DisplayName)->ToString();
  }
```

Comment: Somewhere you have a `using namespace std;` Stop that at once and never do it again. It things you are declaring `text` as a `std::string` and not a `System::String`. This resolves both errors.

Comment: Also, make sure you tag C++-CLI, because that is the correct "language" tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToString()` is returning a managed `System::String` type. This is different from the unmanaged `std::string` type.

To convert from one to the other, use [marshal_as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859.aspx).